# Change name to S-Function Level 2 programmatically

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

I have a S-Function level 2 and i want to change his name.

[image]

I want to change that "mfile" from this image with something else, I want to make that **with code in a function**.
I have a S Function and some inputs and some outputs generated programmatically and I don't know how to change that name with code.
I try [set_param](http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/local-apps/matlabhelp/toolbox/simulink/slref/set_param.html) but no success.

How to change S-Function name programmatically in a function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use set_param to change the FunctionName parameter of that block.

```
set_param(blk, 'FunctionName', 'new_mfile');
```

where blk is the full path of the block, which can be obtained by gcb if the block is selected. 'new_mfile' is the name of your generated MATLAB file.